# Why is my azure pipeline cron job not running?

Tags: azure-devops, cron, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get a cron schedule running by using yaml instead of azure pipeline scheduling.

This is my YAML:

```
trigger: none
pr: none
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build when changes have been pushed
  always: true
  branches:
    include:
    - branch1
    - branch2
variables:
- group: BranchVariables
```

First it ran every time someone made a PR, figured out that I've to add "pr: none". Now I don't know what is missing. What am I potentially missing? The ms documentation is sparsely and I already read all the related topics on this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Update:
When I want to check the schedules on the pipeline it doesn't show me any and I can't sync
[image]

When I edit the pipeline I get the current yaml version on master branch we do not use anymore and is not the default branch. The pipeline should only run for the two branches I include in the yaml branches property.

[image]

The pipeline still didn't run this night and my guess was now that the yaml with the schedules must be also checked into the master branch. I figured out that the default branch can be set for every pipeline and I changed it now and finally can sync and see the schedules. What's still mysterious to me is that I had to add the default pipeline branch to the included branches before the schedules showed up. I'm now using only one included branch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems fine to be with your pipeline. I tested it with this code:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build when changes have been pushed
  always: true
  branches:
    include:
    - branch1
    - branch2
    - master
variables:
- group: BranchVariables

steps:
- script: echo "hello $(test)"
```

Please keep in mind that you have filter for specific branches, so make sure that branch1 or branch2 exists.

I created a new branch `branch1` and changed to default branch for the pipeline and ten synced schedules:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if the default branch in a repository plays a role in regard to scheduling? The YAML hasn't been updated in said default branch and is only committed to the branches which need scheduling. When I want to check "Schedules" it doesn't let me sync it and when I edit the pipeline it always shows me the default repo with the old yaml first.

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you show how this pipelines looks like on main and how on branch1? So I could reproduce your case.